# Counting rows in SQL Server by substrings

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. Currently, I have a table that looks like the following:

```
   Text      DateLogged  SomeID  SomeOtherID
-----------------------------------------------
1234: Data   04/04/2014    1        190
3212: Text   04/04/2014    1        190
4332: Data   04/04/2014    1        190
1256: Data   04/04/2014    1        190
```

as well as the following SQL query:

```
SELECT RIGHT(Text, LEN(Text) - CHARINDEX(':', Text) - 1) AS Sub, DateLogged, SomeID, SomeOtherID
FROM   Example
WHERE  SomeOtherID = 190
```

**I would like to get the counts of rows with the same substring (Sub) for a report that I am building with SSRS.** However, I can't seem to find a way to group the query results by substring (FYI, the DateLogged and SomeID fields are used for grouping in the report). The report would look like the following:

```
Month    SomeID     Sub     Count
---------------------------------
April
            1
                    Data      3
                    Text      1
```

Any solution, whether it is on the query level or the report level, would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This counts the substrings:

```
SELECT RIGHT(Text, LEN(Text) - CHARINDEX(':', Text) - 1) AS Sub, count(*)
FROM   Example
WHERE  SomeOtherID = 190
GROUP BY RIGHT(Text, LEN(Text) - CHARINDEX(':', Text) - 1);
```

If you want the date and other id:

```
SELECT datepart(month, datelogged) as mon,
       RIGHT(Text, LEN(Text) - CHARINDEX(':', Text) - 1) AS Sub,
       someotherid, count(*)
FROM   Example
WHERE  SomeOtherID = 190
GROUP BY datepart(month, datelogged) as mon,
         RIGHT(Text, LEN(Text) - CHARINDEX(':', Text) - 1),
         SomeOtherId;
```

Comment: This is really close to what I wanted, but I am getting a count of 1 for every row (in other words, each row is being counted on its own, and the rows with the same substring aren't being added together).

Comment: Perhaps the strings only appear once?  Or, there are hidden characters that make them different?

Comment: When I choose to treat Sub as a group, it treats them as the same string. But when it is treated as a detail row, it doesn't sum them together. I am starting to think that this is a peculiarity of SSRS.